# ImportError: No module named Crypto

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having my coworker follow the directions on this page to install rosbag
http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows
so that he can reindex corrupted `.bag` files in the future, we've followed the directions to a 'T' but are still receiving this import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\opt\ros\melodic\x64\bin\rosbag", line 34, in <module>
    import rosbag
  File "C:\opt\ros\melodic\x64\lib\site-packages\rosbag\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .bag import Bag, Compression, ROSBagException, ROSBagFormatException, ROSBagUnindexedException
  File "C:\opt\ros\melodic\x64\lib\site-packages\rosbag\bag.py", line 53, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
ImportError: No module named Crypto
```

we tried installing `Crypto` and `pycrypto` manually, which all come back as successfull, but the error persists

```
Specs:
Windows 10
64-Bit
Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition
2019 Build Tools, and the Microsoft C++ Compiler for Python 2.7
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331160/importerror:-no-module-named-crypto/) by [iggy12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/45000/iggy12345/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-08-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LeRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/54918/leros/) on 2020-05-14**:
Hello,

What was the solution to that problem?

Thanks in advance

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-02-03**:
I have a feeling this might not be a `Windows` specific issue. #q370678 shows the same error on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Same as the answer on another thread [#q370678 (answer)](https://answers.ros.org/question/370678/no-module-named-cryptodomex-error-when-running-rosmsg-show/?answer=370930#post-id-370930), a dependency on cryptodome is defined in the very `rosbag` package so it should be installed during (build/)installation of `rosbag`. I'd recommend you to review how you (build/)installed `rosbag`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2021-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for the report. This is the first I've seen of this, so I created a [tracking bug](https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/144) in the ROS on Windows Github.

---

Originally posted by [OoeyGUI](https://answers.ros.org/users/37999/ooeygui/) with karma: 186 on 2019-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just ran into it while creating a new python environment.
Solved it with:
pip install pycryptodome

---

Originally posted by [Yoshi_E](https://answers.ros.org/users/45176/yoshi_e/) with karma: 21 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) on 2020-07-16**:
I passed that stage installing `pycryptodomex` but now I'm at `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gnupg'`

**Comment by [lyh458](https://answers.ros.org/users/50437/lyh458/) on 2020-09-23**:
How did you solve the problem?  Thanks.

**Comment by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) on 2020-09-23**:
I eventually gave up. I don't remember the problem exactly, IIRC I was trying to read the messages from the rosbag directly without doing `rosbag play`. In any case, my problem was elsewhere, I was losing packets because the pipeline in the rest of my code was too slow, so I solved it by optimizing the rest of the code.

**Comment by [lyh458](https://answers.ros.org/users/50437/lyh458/) on 2020-09-23**:
I solved the problem by ran `conda install -c conda-forge python-gnupg` just now. Using ros and anaconda simultaneously maybe the cause of my problem. Thanks anyway.

**Comment by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) on 2020-09-23**:
I checked out my git log, I gave up upon reaching the `import roslz4` necessary to replay my bags. I didn't find the way to import it because it was `Python 2.7` only and I was using `Python 3.6`. So unrelated to `gnupg` at the end of the day.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-02-03**:
Beside my post https://answers.ros.org/question/331160/importerror-no-module-named-crypto/?answer=370932#post-id-370932 is likely more proper fix, using `pip` is *ok* but in general not recommended esp. if you're making software that's meant to be maintained longer term. FYI there's lengthy discussion https://discourse.ros.org/t/should-we-warn-new-users-about-difficulties-with-python-3-and-alternative-python-interpreters/3874